# String.Equals vs String.Compare vs "==" in Action. Explanation needed

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-comparison

Following is the code snippet from a console application -

```
class MyClass
{        
   public int GetDay(string data22)
    {
        int returnValue = 0;

        if (string.Compare(data22,"THURSDAY") == 0) // true
        {
            returnValue = (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        }

        if (data22 == "THURSDAY") //false
        {
            returnValue = (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        }

        if (string.Equals(data22, "THURSDAY"))//false
        {
            returnValue = (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ExecutionDay = "‎THURSDAY";
        MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
        int MyDays = obj1.GetDay(ExecutionDay);
    }
}
```

Question is - Why does the first comparison (string.compare) work and the other two comparison methods does not work in THIS PARTICULAR CASE ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why does the first comparison (string.compare) work and the other two
>   comparison methods does not work in THIS PARTICULAR CASE

There are invisible characters (particularly, a [Left-to-Right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) (Thanks @MatthewWatson)) in your code. You can view them with any hex editor:

[image]

This is over-looked by `string.Compare`, while it isn't with `string.Equals`. You can see it in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Notes to Callers:
>
> Character sets include ignorable characters. The
>   Compare(String, String) method **does not consider such characters when
>   it performs a culture-sensitive comparison.** For example, if the
>   following code is run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a
>   culture-sensitive comparison of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft
>   hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalent.

Comment: Well spotted. Specifically, the extra single Unicode character at the start of the string is a ["Left-to-right" mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Yuval and Matthew. So in my case what should be right way of comparison. Should I stick with string.compare or use anything else. Pl suggest.

Comment: @Subhasis I would suggest sticking with `string.Equals`. You could sanitize the strings before checking for equality.

Comment: @XiaoPeng-Zenuml_com It's a hidden character. You can see it in the image prepended to "THURSDAY".

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I meant how did you find it. Did Subhasis post that image or did he shared the code somewhere else?

Comment: @XiaoPeng-Zenuml_com I copy pasted his code into Notepad++ and viewed it with the Hex plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The `ExecutionDay` string contains invisible characters, otherwise all checks would be true

The following lines return a different length, 9 and 8 respectively

```
        Console.WriteLine(ExecutionDay.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("THURSDAY".Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an "invisible" character at the beginning of your

```
string ExecutionDay = "‎THURSDAY";
```

and it is the [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm). You can check it with:

```
int len = ExecutionDay.Length; // 9 instead of 8
```

and

```
char ch = ExecutionDay[0]; // 8206
```

Comment: It's already visible in the source code of this website: <span class="str">"&lrm;‎THURSDAY"</span>

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh Yep `&lrm;` :-)

Answer (score 0):

In short CompareTo is culture dependent. For example [ß (s sharp from German)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F):

```
Console.WriteLine("ß Compare ss 1: " + ("ß".CompareTo("ss") == 0));
Console.WriteLine("ß Compare ss 2: " + (String.Compare("ß", "ss", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0));
Console.WriteLine("ß equals ss: " + "ß".Equals("ss"));
Console.WriteLine("ß == ss: " + ("ß" == "ss"));
```

Would print out

```
ß Compare ss 1: True
ß Compare ss 2: False
ß equals ss: False
ß == ss: False
```

In your case you have string that look the same, but are different. Usally I find it helpful to see the difference, this can be done with:

```
Console.WriteLine(
  string.Join(", ", 
    ExecutionDay
      .ToCharArray()
      .Select(o =((int)o).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
      .AsEnumerable()
  )
);
```

resulting in character number code list:

```
8206, 84, 72, 85, 82, 83, 68, 65, 89
```

Where character `8206` in unicode is `left-to-right mark`.

---

## == comparison

This will compare values ONLY IF it is a value type or primitive. Other then that it is and should be used as REFERENCE comparison. In C#, type string is special and both of 2 following assertions would yield to **true**:

```
string ss = getinput();//"SS"
assertTrue("SS"=="SS");
assertTrue( ss =="SS");
```

In Java however first will return true beacuse JIT runtime optimizer that collects all unique strings from code and creates a table that is used. Second one false, as string is just immutable character array and if entered by user a new memory space is used thus reference comparison returns **false**.

[C# Guidelines for Implementing Equals and the Equality Operator (==)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7h9bszxx(v=vs.100).aspx)

## Equals comparison

Unlike **==** Equals method is just a virtual one defined in System.Object, and overridden by whichever classes choose to do so. Therefor the overridden version will be used and in case of string type this means contents comparison will be done.

> Follow these guidelines when overriding Equals(Object):
>
> - Types that implement IComparable must override Equals(Object).
> - Types that override Equals(Object) must also override GetHashCode; otherwise, hash tables might not work correctly.
> - You should consider implementing the IEquatable interface to support strongly typed tests for equality. Your IEquatable.Equals
>   implementation should return results that are consistent with Equals.
> - If your programming language supports operator overloading and you overload the equality operator for a given type, you must also
>   override the Equals(Object) method to return the same result as the
>   equality operator. This helps ensure that class library code that uses
>   Equals (such as ArrayList and Hashtable) behaves in a manner that is
>   consistent with the way the equality operator is used by applicat

[C# Implementing the Equals Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx)

## ComparedTo comparison

> #### Caution
>
> The **CompareTo** method was designed primarily for
> use in sorting or alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when
> the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two
> strings are equivalent. To determine whether two strings are
> equivalent, call the Equals method.

This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture. For more information about word, string, and ordinal sorts, see System.Globalization.CompareOptions.

Source : [Manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx)