# unable to get data from database by passing string value in entity frame work asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

i am trying to get data from database passing a string value. but get null value instead of the data. 
i have tried the following code

```
order getCustomerOrder(string or_n)
        {
            using (foodorderingEntities db = new foodorderingEntities ())
            {
                var result = db.orders.Where(or => or.order_no == or_n).FirstOrDefault();
                return result;
            }
        }
```

please some one guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Leading/trailing spaces? Case differences? Not looking at the right database? Etc. Not much we can say with this tiny bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your order object, so we know if its reference object/primitive etc, you can use this to understand the two ways to retrieve orders.

I would recommend you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885034/string-equals-vs-string-compare-vs-in-action-explanation-needed) & this [MSDN string compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings), if your default culture is causing an issue in the comparison, it will help you understand whats going on

Options 1:

```
// Query syntax
IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> queryResultsCustomerOrder =
    from order in orders
    where order.number == myOrderNumber
    select order;
```

Options 2:

```
// Method-based syntax
IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> queryResultsCustomerOrder2 = orders.Where(order => order.Number == myOrderNumber);
```

---

using the above, now you can get however many orders the customer has. *I am assuming your order is a number, but you can change it to whatever like a string.*

`Int` based order comparison sample

```
 IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> getCustomerOrder(int myOrderNumber)
    {
       if(myOrderNumber <1) return null;

        using (foodorderingEntities dbContextOrderSet = new foodorderingEntities())
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> resultsOneOrManyOrders = orders.Where(order => order.Number == myOrderNumber);
            return resultsOneOrManyOrders ;
        }
    }
```

`string` based order comparison

```
 IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> getCustomerOrder(string myOrderNumber)
    {
       //no orders
       if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myOrderNumber)) return null;

        using (foodorderingEntities dbContextOrderSet = new foodorderingEntities())
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> resultsOneOrManyOrders = orders.Where(order => order.Number == myOrderNumber);
            // you can replace the *** comparison with .string.Compare and try inside the block

            return resultsOneOrManyOrders ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the query is translated into SQL. Adding string.Compare with comparison options isn't supported. For the same reason, the client culture doesn't affect the comparison. It's the database collation that matters.